# Measuring the distance between matrices with different dimensions

Tags: matlab, distance, dimensions

I have two matrices, one matrix with values ranging from `0-1`, and another having only values of `0` and `1`. I'm interested in calculating the distance only to those pixels equal to `1`. In this case, I thought of making a new matrix that only contains the pixels with value `1` from the second object and then taking the distance to those. But, in this case, the dimensions will differ.

Note: The two matrices are originally of the same dimension. But, there are many cels not of interest (i.e; those having value `0`)

How can I perform such distance calculation with objects of different dimensions?

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is not clearly stated. Please edit it and define what an object is, what an object with values ranging from 0-1 means, etc.

Comment: We would also need to know if these matrices are the same dimensions to start with. If not, then how do the indices in one matrix map to the other to start with?

Comment: Thanks. I have made an edit to my question. Is it more clear now?

Answer (score 0):

If the positions of the pixels are not important to the calculation, then you can use logical indexing like so:

```
A = [0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1]; 
B = rand(size(A));
nonZeroInd = A == 1;
Anz = A(nonZeroInd);
Bnz = B(nonZeroInd);
dist = Bnz - Anz;
```

If you need the results in a matrix in the same positions as the original then you can do

```
C = zeros(size(A));
C(nonZeroInd) = dist;
```